# How to find all files in a Directory with grep and regex?

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I have a Directory(Linux/Unix) on a Apache Server with a lot of subdirectory containing lot of files like this:

```
- Dir  
  - 2010_01/
    - 142_78596_101_322.pdf
    - 12_10.pdf
    - ...
  - 2010_02/   
    - ...
```

How can i find all files with filesnames looking like: `*_*_*_*.pdf` ? where * is always a digit!!

I try to solve it like this:

```
ls -1Rl 2010-01 | grep -i '\(\d)+[_](\d)+[_](\d)+[_](\d)+[.](pdf)$' | wc -l
```

But the regular expression `\(\d)+[_](\d)+[_](\d)+[_](\d)+[.](pdf)$` doesn't work with grep.

**Edit 1**: Trying `ls -l 2010-03 | grep -E '(\d+_){3}\d+\.pdf' | wc -l` for example just return null. So it's dont work perfectly

Comment: \d means digit, so your regex is looking for:  digits_digits_digits_digits.pdf.  What kind of filenames are there that you don't want to match?

Comment: Are you trying to match `12_10.pdf` or only `142_78596_101_322.pdf` in the example?

Comment: i'm trying to match the second one!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **gbchaosmaster** and **the wolf** I find a way which work for me:

**Into a Directory**:

```
find . | grep -P "(\d+_){3}\d+\.pdf" | wc -l
```

**At the Root Directory**:

```
find 20*/ | grep -P "(\d+_){3}\d+\.pdf" | wc -l
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `find`.

The command that satisfies your specification `__*_*.pdf where * is always a digit`:

```
find 2010_10/ -regex '__\d+_\d+\.pdf'
```

You seem to be wanting a sequence of 4 numbers separated by underscores, however, based on the regex that you tried.

```
(\d+_){3}\d+\.pdf
```

Or do you want to match all names containing solely numbers/underscores?

```
[\d_]+\.pdf
```

Comment: The stackoverflow formatted deleted some characters! files have the format `*_*_*_*.pdf` I will try the regex you posted!!

Comment: i try `(\d+_){3}\d+\.pdf` with find and grep without success!!

Comment: I'm not in an environment where I am able to test this, but you may need to add the `-regextype posix-extended` flag to the `find` command.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should be using egrep vs grep or call grep with -E for extended patterns.

So this works for me:

```
$ cat test2.txt
- Dir  
  - 2010_01/
    - 142_78596_101_322.pdf
    - 12_10.pdf
    - ...
  - 2010_02/   
    - ...
```

Now egrep that file:

```
cat test2.txt | egrep '((?:\d+_){3}(?:\d+)\.pdf$)'
- 142_78596_101_322.pdf
```

Since there are parenthesis around the whole pattern, the entire file name will be captured.

Note that the pattern does NOT work with grep in traditional mode:

```
$ cat test2.txt | grep '((?:\d+_){3}(?:\d+)\.pdf$)'
... no return
```

But DOES work if you use the extend pattern switch (the same as calling egrep):

```
$ cat test2.txt | grep -E '((?:\d+_){3}(?:\d+)\.pdf$)'
- 142_78596_101_322.pdf
```